# Appium Java: How do I use the TouchAction class or something equivalent with AndroidDriver?

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am using Appium Java client 8.5.1 and selenium version 4.10.0. I am trying to automate having the user touch a point on the screen (specified by me). I tried using this line:

```
WebDriver theDriver = new AndroidDriver(url, cap);
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(theDriver);
```

However, I get an error that says that "The constructor TouchAction(WebDriver) is undefined".

The PerformsTouchAction class is deprecated, and to be honest, the TouchAction class is too.

I found something called TapOptions, but it doesn't take a webdriver into its constructor.

```
TapOptions action = new TapOptions();
```

Without taking the driver in, how would I apply this to my automation? Is there some alternative way to automating the ability to tap a specified (x,y) point on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in 2 ways.

1. **W3C action API:**
   If you prefer generic solution to work on multiple platform then W3C
   action is a way to go. W3C Actions (WebDriver Actions) in Appium refer to a
   standardized way of performing user interactions and gestures on
   mobile applications, following the WebDriver specification. Additional
   info you can find [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver2/#dfn-actions).

   Here's an example to construct horizontal scroll using actions API

   ```
   WebElement slider = 
   driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("slider"));

   Point source = slider.getLocation();

   PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, 
   "finger");
   Sequence sequence = new Sequence(finger, 1);

   sequence.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(ofMillis(0),
       PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), source.x, source.y + 400));
   sequence.addAction(
       finger.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.MIDDLE.asArg()));
   sequence.addAction(new Pause(finger, ofMillis(600)));
   sequence.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(ofMillis(600),
       PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), source.x, source.y));
   sequence.addAction(
       finger.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.MIDDLE.asArg()));

   driver.perform(singletonList(sequence));
   ```
2. **Android specific gestures:**
   In Appium, you can perform various Android-specific gestures to simulate
   user interactions on Android devices. These gestures are used to test
   the functionality and behavior of mobile applications. Additional
   info you can find [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver/blob/master/docs/android-mobile-gestures.md).

   Here's an example to construct horizontal scroll using android specific
   gestures

   ```
   driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId("slider"));
   Point source = slider.getLocation();

   driver.executeScript("mobile: scrollGesture", ImmutableMap.of("left", 
   source.x, "top", source.y + 400, "width", source.x, "height", source.y,
   "direction", "down","percent", 1));
   ```